# A tangent is drawn to the parabola $y^2=4x$ at the point P whose abscissa lies in the interval $[1,4]$.

Tags: conic-sections

> A tangent is drawn to the parabola $y^2=4x$ at the point P whose abscissa lies in the interval $[1,4]$. Find the maximum area of the triangle formed by the tangent at P, ordinate of point P and the X axis.

The point P will be $(t^2,2t)$

The tangent will be
$$ty=x+t^2$$
At y=0
$$x=-t^2$$

Let the ordinate of P be PN and the tangent intersects the X axis at point A

$\Delta =\frac 12 PN. AN$

I can’t find those distances, since there is no data given. My guess is that PN will be the semi - latusrectum of the parabolla, but I am not sure.

Comment: Given the symmetry It is simpler if you take the equation $y=2\sqrt{x}$

Comment: $PN=y=2t$, $AN=t^2+t^2=2t^2$.

Comment: @Aretino why is $AN=t^2+t^2$?

Comment: Because $N_x=P_x=x^2$ and $A_x=-t^2$ (from your equations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the equation $yy_0=2(x+x_0)$ for the tangent at the point $(x_0,y_0)$.  So this line intersects the $x$-axis at $x=-x_0$. $|PN|=|y_0|=2\sqrt{x_0}$ and $|AN|=2x_0$. Now by the formula for the area of the triangle $$S(x_0)=\frac{1}{2}|PN|\cdot|AN|=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2x_0\cdot2\sqrt{x_0}=2x_0\sqrt{x_0}$$ Since $S(x_0)$ is an increasing function it attains its maximum value at the end of the segment. Hence, $$S(x_0) \le 2\cdot4\cdot\sqrt{4}=16$$
So the answer is 16.

Comment: Why is $AN=2x_0$?

Comment: $N(x_0,0)$ and $A(-x_0,0)$. Thus $|AN|=\sqrt{(x_0+x_0)^2+(0-0)^2}=2x_0$ @Aditya